# Simplifying a sum?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, summation

Define polynomials $P_{j,s}^{(r)}$ via the generating series $$\left(\frac{d^s}{dz^s}f(z)\right)^r=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} P_{j,s}^{(r)}z^j,$$ where $r\geq 1$. Here, $f(z)=z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+\cdots.$ I was hoping to simplify the expression $$ 3\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}P_{j-k-1,s}^{(r-1)}P_{k,s-1}^{(1)}+(s-2)\sum_{k=0}^j P_{j-k,s}^{(r-1)}P_{k,s-1}^{(1)}, $$ where $j\geq 1$ and $s\geq 2$

Comment: Have you tried to see what happen by examples like $f(z) = e^{\lambda z}$? If not, how about to start with it?

Comment: Your first summand is $3$ times the coefficient of $z^{j-1}$ in the power series $\bigl[f^{(s)}\bigr]^{r-1}\cdot f^{(s-1)}$. Similarly, your second summand is $s-2$ times the coefficient of $z^j$ in the power series $\bigl[f^{(s)}\bigr]^{r-1}\cdot f^{(s-1)}$. If were $s+1$ instead of $s-1$, then by chain rule you would have $\bigl[f^{(s)}\bigr]^{r-1}\cdot f^{(s+1)}=\frac1r\bigl[\bigl(f^{(s)}\bigr)^r\bigr]^\prime$...but who said that life was easy?